# Restricting IP address not working in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

In the default configuration of phpmyadmin with ISPconfig-3 on Ubuntu. Strange thing happens, "Order Deny,Allow" & "Deny from All" works for sub-directories (blocks all requests) but not for the root of them.

/usr/share/phpmyadmin (Not working)

/usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup (working)

/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries (working)

/usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib (working)

Can you explain this behavior? Do i miss something?

Of course I'm not going to block it at all but when it fails to bock all IPs except mine I tried to test blocking all but it fails!

Note: Ubuntu version 12.04.5 LTS

Here is the /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        ......
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from All

</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All

    .......
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out there is a configuration duplication. The main configuration file of PhpMyAdmin package (/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf) configure the directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin", and ISPConfig re-configured it again in "/etc/apache2/sites-available/ispconfig.conf"! Honestly I didn't expect this duplication but I choose to disable the one in "/etc/apache2/sites-available/ispconfig.conf" and restriction now works.

ISPConfig is great but I think developers should consider this small issue and alike.